# Unable to write data into the saved files in android

Tags: java, android

*I am stuck from last few days with the problem of writing data into files. I am capturing an image from the designed camera app. I am trying to write the timestamp values at which image was clicked onto   a csv file. I am able to properly generate and store the .csv and image files onto the sd card but when it comes onto the writing the timestamp data into csv file, I am noticing that the .csv files are empty. 
Can someone kindly help me out in solving this issue. I am attaching the code bit for reference. 
Thank you.

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {
private static final String LOG_TAG = "CameraActivity.java";
private static final int IMAGE_CAPTURE = 0;
File fileName; 
PrintWriter captureFile;
double timeStamp = 0;
int x = 1;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera);
    try {
        // intent to start device camera
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        // you can also create your own filename or path
        String fileN = "camera_app";
        //String fileName = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
        // where do you want to save the images
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                + fileN + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(path);

        // if the file name already exists, append __x on the file name
        do {
            path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                    + fileN + "__" + x + ".jpg";
            file = new File(path);
            captureFile = null;
            fileName = null;
            sdcard();   
            x++;

        } while (file.exists());

        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        // 0, this code will be returned in onActivityResult() when the
        // activity exits.
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
private void sdcard() {
    try {

        fileName = new  FileEnvironment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"CameraData"+                                                  "__" + Integer.toString(x) +".csv" );
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileName,false);
        captureFile = new PrintWriter (writer);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
// activity exits
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    try {
        if (requestCode == IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if( captureFile != null ){
                saveTimeStamp();    
                }
                                    takeAnother();
            } 
        } 
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void saveTimeStamp() {

    try {
        timeStamp=System.currentTimeMillis();
        captureFile.println(timeStamp + "," + x);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Saved TimeStamp.");
        captureFile.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if( captureFile != null ) {
        try {
            captureFile.close();
    //      writer.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    CameraActivity.this.finish();
}
public void takeAnother() {
    try {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("The Code Of A Ninja")
                .setMessage("Do you want to take another picture?")
                .setPositiveButton("YES", new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0,    int arg1) {
                        arg0.dismiss();


                        Intent nextActivity = new Intent(
                                   CameraActivity.this, CameraActivity.class);
                        CameraActivity.this.finish();
                        startActivity(nextActivity);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("NO", new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        arg0.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this,
                                "Done taking picture.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();




                        // go to main activity
                        CameraActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                }).show();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}*
```

Comment: Your code is hard to read.  First of all, you should really learn how to use the debugger.  Logcat and Toast are a lousy way of troubleshooting apps.  Secondly, please remove all the logs and toasts from your code so that it's easier to read.

Comment: On the contrary, please **do not** remove the logging - it's a fine way to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
 FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileName,false);
```

to this one:

```
 FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileName,true);
```

Comment: Please don't just post code.  What did you change and why?  Without this, the OP (and future visitors) learn nothing.

Comment: Thank you Dyna...it worked. But can I ask you a question why did you  made a change to true. Though I am writing at the starting of the file not appending it. Thanks for your help

Comment: Simon I just removed the toasts and logs as you did mention in the last post, however thanks for your suggestion as my problem is solved. However, I will keep in mind your suggestions when I am posting my code or problems next time.

Comment: @RockStar If you want to know why, just see the documentation - http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileWriter.html

Comment: You are right @Simon but I was in a hurry, do you need some further explanation @RockStar? Did this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not to familiar with the methods you are using to write your data to a file, but i would start by making sure you have the proper permissions in the manifest file. The following XML should be a child of the manifest's element:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

This enables Android to write to the internal and the external storage drives.